# Background-Image Not Dynamic through Navigation

Tags: php, css, background-image

It's been a damn long while since I've coded anything and I've recently set up a new site once again based on the popular Minecraft franchise. Anywho, I'm having a little trouble when it comes to actually displaying the navigational bar as I'd like. Essentially, I have a background image that I want to span across the logo, navigation and the social media icons, the image in question is:

http://minethediamond.com/wp-content/themes/minethediamond/img/navbg.jpg

And that is the problem. I have a section container for the ul classes of the logo, navigation and social icons but it merely spans just the logo and nothing more and I have no idea why. The site as you can see is located at MineTheDiamond.com.

For specific code that I have added, it is essentially this in the CSS:

`.top-bar-section {background-image: url('../img/navbg.jpg'); width: auto; }`

There are also a few other dead-end style uses that I tried to duplicate in the CSS to actually get the navigation showing but as aforementioned, it didn't work.

And of course, the obligatory stuff in the header section:

```
<div class="large-3 small-12 columns">
            <P><P><div class="navcontainer"><div id="minenav">  
<section class="top-bar-section"><ul class="left"><div id="logo">
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>"
                       title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name', 'display')); ?>" rel="home">
                        <img src="<?php /* Use the default logo (logo.png) if custom logo does not exist */
                        if ($smof_data['pkb_custom_logo']) : echo $smof_data['custom_logo']; else: echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/logo.png<?php endif; ?>"
                             alt=" logo"/>
                    </a></ul>



                            <?php
                            wp_nav_menu(array(
                                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                'container' => false,
                                'depth' => 0,
                                'items_wrap' => '<ul class="left">%3$s</ul>',
                                'fallback_cb' => 'menu_fallback', // workaround to show a message to set up a menu
                                'walker' => new peekaboo_walker(array(
                                    'in_top_bar' => true,
                                    'item_type' => 'li'
                                )),
                            ));
                            ?>
                            <?php include 'incl/social-toolbox.php'; ?></section>
                        </div>`
```

Thanks in advance, all! :)

Comment: 1. What are the <p><p> for?  2. Did hyou try making the ul and div inside background transparent?

Comment: <p> <p> is just so I could see what I was doing whilst logged in and ensure everything is fine before I added various margins. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick, just position the element and have background-size: cover;

```
.top-bar-section {
     background-image: url('../img/navbg.jpg');
     width: auto;
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     background-size: cover;
}
```

[image]

You may have some IE8 issues that are worth looking into but this should work for most.

And if you want the top section to span the entire header just change your width from auto to 100%

Comment: This has solved the problems that I was having but now I am worried about workarounds for IE8; is it worth just doing the navigation bar in Photoshop to ensure that everything is fine across browsers or is there a workaround?

Comment: @StevenR You can do, I generally don't worry too much about it, I would check your analytics when the site is live and if there are a large portion of IE8 users then look at doing something, on my sites they represent a small number but this is a decision you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at `background-size:cover` in order to contain the whole div with single image

be aware that this will not work in IE8 so it should be backed with a fallback

Read here for more details
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Hi, thanks for the assistance! It's now covering the entire area but for some reason, it is no longer separated over the x-axis, and is instead just going downwards in a list format? Any assistance? Sorry to be a pain!

Comment: look for this line `<div class="large-3 small-12 columns">` @StevenR change to `large-12` and there is no point in putting small-12 here